# How to detect irregular activity in LAN/PC?

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I want to be notified via email if any of these events below happen:

1. New device came online on my LAN (basically accessed my WiFi)
2. Failed authentication attempts on my PC
3. Someone or something scanning my PC's ports
4. My PC was woken up
5. My PC was logged into (from the login screen and via SSH)
6. ARP poisoning or similar techniques are being used on my network

How could I monitor those events and be notified with email (also if possible an Unity notification would be nice)?

Comment: I think this should be reopened because a) I found OSSEC that does 4/6 of those things and b) I wouldn't say a year of looking around and finding only one piece of software that does this is in any means broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution here would be using **OSSEC**.

It can be downloaded from [here](https://ossec.github.io/downloads.html).

By default it doesn't perform all six required functions listed in the question, some additional software has to be installed, by default OSSEC keeps watch of these four things (email alerts might have to be enabled separately for lower level notifications):

1) Failed authentication attempts
2) Port scans, you can read more about it from the documentation [here](https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual/notes/portscan_detection.html).
3) Device booting up
4) Logging in

These two have to be separately enabled or configured:

5) ARP poisoning detection
6) Detecting new host on network should also be enabled when arpwatch (previous) ruleset is enabled

You can find the arpwatch ruleset [here](https://github.com/ossec/ossec-hids/blob/master/etc/rules/arpwatch_rules.xml) or in the ruleset folder of your install.

Answer (score 2):

There's plenty you can do with security, all of which will be great education!

I've used [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8) to prevent repeated access attempts mostly for http hack attempts. it reads log files so is very very configurable, it's a bit complicated but well worth reading up on.

You can see who last logged in using the **lastlog** command.

The command **sudo arp** will show you the addresses on your network so you can identify potential spoofing with MAC addresses you don't recognise.

**iptables** which fail2ban also uses can be used to deny a specific IP address or protocol. (careful with that though, unless you have physical access).

Going a bit more into networking you could look up **wireshark** this can capture traffic and show ARP requests.

All this is good practice but I find mostly what you need is to use WPA2 with a long password on your WiFi, change it from the one that's probably printed on your router.

Use [Private key authentication over SSH](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/530/SSH_with_authentication_key_instead_of_password). (Also be very careful here)

Hope that covers most of what you want. It's a lot to work with; so can't explain how to use everything here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I really don't wish to look at the logs all the time and be near the machine. That's why I wrote about email sending.

Comment: Apologies!. I missed the bit about *email*. I also just looked at [this page](http://www.tecmint.com/get-root-ssh-login-email-alerts-in-linux/) which uses .bashrc commands upon login, which could be used to write a string of text or to a file and email yourself the alert/details.

Comment: Interesting. If I will have to monitor everything separately with some kind of scripts I'll give this link a go.

Answer (score 1):

**Inbuilt tools:**(need to download from Ubuntu)

**1** .New device came online on my LAN (basically accessed my WiFi)

```
ifconfig -a
```

**2** . Failed authentication attempts on my PC([fail2ban](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-ssh-with-fail2ban-on-ubuntu-14-04))

```
apt-get install fail2ban
cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
nano /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

need to add below lines w.r.t your service

```
bantime = 600
findtime = 600
maxretry = 3
```

for example authentication fail:

```
[ssh]

enabled  = true
port     = ssh
filter   = sshd
logpath  = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
```

fail2ban also have email notify service.

```
destemail = root@localhost
sendername = Fail2Ban
mta = sendmail
```

**3**.Someone or something scanning my PC's ports(helpful command)

```
netstat -an (to see which port are open and connected to other network)
```

**iftop** (monitoring the bandwidth of LAN,WLAN network)

```
apt-get install iftop
iftop
```

Then press p(port) and n(DNS). once you know once on which port traffic is coming from unknown ip. you can block that ip with ufw firewall.

```
ufw deny from 192.x.x.x
```

To check if someone is scanning port:

`netstat -an` and `iftop`

if the output of above command is long list and connection is coming from same ip on multiple ports.

**5**.My PC was logged into (then it would be nice to get last 10 commands issued)

```
history
```

will give you the the last 2K command used (if the user is same)

**OR**

To see other user's command used (eg. user=test)

```
su test
history
```

above command need sudo or root privilege.

Software used for monitoring linux system:

Nagios : https://www.nagios.org/projects/

Splunk : http://www.splunk.com/en_us/download/splunk-enterprise.html

Zabbix : http://www.zabbix.com/download.php

All above tools have notify emails service.(highly customizable)

**Update:**

Notify user lgoin via email : https://www.tiger-computing.co.uk/get-linux-to-notify-every-ssh-login/

```
nano /etc/profile

if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
TEXT="$(date): ssh login to ${USER}@$(hostname -f)"
TEXT="$TEXT from $(echo $SSH_CLIENT|awk '{print $1}')" 
echo $TEXT|mail -s "ssh login" you@your.domain
fi
```

Comment: **2.** Does fail2ban work with SSH key based auth failures and physical login attempts?  **3.** I know what's open. I just want to know if there's someone else looking for open ports.   **5.** How do I make it automatically email it to me when user logs in?

Comment: 2. what is physical login attempts? will work on when username/password wrong. 3. update answer 5.update answer, Welcome to ubuntu ask one question in one post.

Comment: Physical login attempt is a person using a keyboard and trying the password. I asked one question actually. Other have been for asking for more details.

Comment: fail2ban will work fine. you need to set "maxretry = 1" but it will ban that ip with email notification.